# Laravel model::whereIn is slower than DB::whereIn

Tags: php, laravel

This query takes 2.3 seconds,

```
Click::whereIn(
    'campaign_id',
    [162, 165, 189, 190, 191, 195, 196, 202, 203, 208, 209]
)->get()
```

[image]

And same query in db form takes 300ms.

```
DB::table('clicks')->whereIn(
    'campaign_id',
    [162, 165, 189, 190, 191, 195, 196, 202, 203, 208, 209]
)->get()
```

[image]

Comment: Your debugbar is showing 200ms and 152ms (for the exact same query). The difference in time is probably to do with creating instances for `Click` because all the model boostrap functions run and relevant model events are triggered for each model insantiated. It's a good idea to keep things that happen when you create a new model instance to a minimum

Comment: @apokryfos `Click` had owen-it/laravel-auditing setup. I removed it and the load time got decreased by a second but it is slower than DB::whereIn.

Comment: You need to carefully check what happens when each `Click` model is instantiated. As you have seen yourself, the database query being done is exactly the same so the time difference is only with what happens when a each `Click` model is instatiated since `DB` only instiates simple `stdClass` objects which are potentially faster to create.

Comment: Telescope and auditing were the culprits. It's normal now.

Answer (score 0):

- Because nature of Laravel ORM query is slower than Query Builder
- [You can see post](https://devsenv.com/tutorials/laravel-eloquent-vs-db-query-builder-performance-and-other-statistics)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `whereIntegerInRaw` instead of whereIn for large int whereIn's? I read an article a long while back that explained that it was because of a bug in PDO (not Laravel). I noticed considerable gains by using the whereIntegerInRaw instead of whereIn.